# PostgreSQL - Regular Expression - SQL state: 42601 syntax error

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I am trying to create tables which include the word "Messdaten" in it. Without ~ "Messdaten" part, code works well, but whenever I add ~ "Messdaten" it throws SQL State: 42601 sytax error. Do you have any idea what is wrong with the code? Its postgresql 9.2.

```
DECLARE
tbl_arr varchar[] := array['Messdaten2','dumptable'];
i varchar;
BEGIN
FOREACH i IN Array tbl_arr
LOOP
EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I AS SELECT * FROM %I ~ "Messdaten"','backup_'||i,i);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is trying to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE Messdaten2 AS SELECT * FROM Messdaten2 ~ "Messdaten"
```

which is incorrect since Messadaten2 is the table name not the member of an expression.

Instead, put the regular expression check outside of the first parameter string of the `format` function:

```
IF i ~ 'Messdaten' THEN -- Do the regular expresssion test here
   EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I AS SELECT * FROM %I','backup_'||i,i);
END IF;
```

Comment: It works but what do you mean by outside of the code? outside of the sql query? I have tried to put the reqular expression to the foreach part which is also outside of the query but didn't work, I am confused now = )
BEGIN
FOREACH i IN Array tbl_arr ~ 'Messdaten'
LOOP